# Double.valueOf(s) vs. Double.parseDouble

Tags: java, methods

Casting an Object to a double and noticed both these methods. I see that parseDouble has been in since 1.2. Why add this method if it essentially does the same functionality as valueOf(s)?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`parseDouble()` returns a primitive `double` value. `valueOf()` returns an instance of the wrapper class `Double`. Before Java 5 introduced autoboxing, that was a very significant difference (and many would argue it still is).

Comment: Nice I just discovered the difference via some overloading. Now to look up autoboxing

Answer (score 20):

Because it is not the same. `valueOf()` creates a `Double` object which is often not needed. `parseDouble()` does not. With autoboxing it's `valueOf(String)` which is no longer needed, but is therefore backward compatibility.

Answer (score 7):

If you just need the value (primitive) use `parseDouble(String s)` the cost is less.   `valueOf(String s)` returns a Double class which wraps the primitive double value.