# Multiplication of java float variable

Tags: java

I have a piece of code as below.

```
String wtf = "8.40";
float ft = Float.parseFloat(wtf); //8.4
ft *= 100.0F;
```

the value of "ft" above is coming as 839.99994

I expected output as 840.00000
How can I correct my code so that it gives me 840.00000 as output

Comment: problem -> http://floating-point-gui.de/, solution -> use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String wtf = "8.40";
    double ft = Double.parseDouble(wtf); //8.4
    ft *= 100.0F;
```

There's is a lot of rounding when you use float. This is why you get this "unexpected" value. And I use parseDouble because the cost is less.

I suggest using BigDecimal for arithmetic and calculations.

```
BigDecimal BDa = new BigDecimal("8.40");
BigDecimal BDc = BDa.multiply(new BigDecimal("100.0"));
```

Comment: So why should you think this will gonna work?

Comment: @rakeb.mazharul http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255078/double-valueofs-vs-double-parsedouble

Comment: We again faced problem with this...String wtf = "9.78";
     double ft = Double.parseDouble(wtf); 
   ft *= 100.0D; // This is returning 977.999999, but it should return us 978

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal Use BigDecimal instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double.valueOf(wtf)` instead of `Float.parseFloat(wtf)`